# Create binary variable based on length of group in another column

Tags: r, group-by, mutate

I need to create a binary variable called flow.type based on the length of a variable called 'cluster'. If the length of a cluster is 1 then flow.type should be "0", and if >1 then flow.type should be "1". I have put an example of my data in the image but please let me know if there's a way to do attach data to my question and i will do that asap. I've tried the code below but it doesnt work for some reason, is there something i am doing wrong?
thanks in advance.

```
# to determine flow type from the clustered groups, use binary version of if/else statement
# flow.type 1 = 'event'
# flow.type 0 = 'non-event'
y <- y %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  mutate(flow.type = case_when(length(cluster)>1 ~ "1",
                                    TRUE ~ "0")) %>% ungroup()
```

[image]

Here is a sample of the data by dput

```
structure(list(Station = c("1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", 
"1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", 
"1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051017", "1051021", 
"1051021", "1051021", "1051021", "1051021"), Site.Name = c("Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", "Laura River at Carroll's Crossing", 
"Laura River at Broken Dam Station", "Laura River at Broken Dam Station", 
"Laura River at Broken Dam Station", "Laura River at Broken Dam Station", 
"Laura River at Broken Dam Station"), Date.Time = c("20/10/2017 7:45", 
"24/10/2017 10:57", "27/12/2019 9:15", "16/01/2020 9:32", "15/04/2020 9:45", 
"12/05/2020 14:30", "17/06/2020 15:55", "11/09/2020 9:16", "12/01/2021 19:44", 
"13/01/2021 12:00", "27/01/2021 15:59", "27/01/2021 16:29", "27/01/2021 17:00", 
"19/02/2021 9:30", "17/01/2022 10:17", "27/12/2019 8:10", "31/12/2019 8:30", 
"21/01/2020 14:25", "21/01/2020 14:47", "14/05/2020 15:15"), 
    Date = structure(c(17459, 17463, 18257, 18277, 18367, 18394, 
    18430, 18516, 18639, 18640, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18677, 19009, 
    18257, 18261, 18282, 18282, 18396), class = "Date"), Datedigit = c(17459745, 
    174631057, 18257915, 18277932, 18367945, 183941430, 184301555, 
    18516916, 186391944, 186401200, 186541559, 186541629, 186541700, 
    18677930, 190091017, 18257810, 18261830, 182821425, 182821447, 
    183961515), Sampling.Year = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
    ), .Label = c("2015-2016", "2016-2017", "2017-2018", "2018-2019", 
    "2019-2020", "2020-2021", "2021-2022", "2022-2023"), class = "factor"), 
    Season = c("Dry", "Dry", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Dry", "Dry", 
    "Dry", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", 
    "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Dry"), cluster = c(56, 57, 58, 59, 
    60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 67, 66, 67, 68, 68, 
    69)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: You should share your data using, for example, `dput(head(y, 20))`.  An image is of little use.  What does 'doesn't work' mean?  You need to be specific about what is happening.  Error?  Result not as expected?  It looks as if it should work although you can simplify it slightly to `y %>% group_by(cluster) %>% mutate(flow.type = case_when(n() > 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% ungroup()` or really just use `flow.type = n() > 1` to return a logical vector.

Comment: What is the "length" of a cluster? For the first row, is the "length" 55? In R the length of a dataframe is the number of columns and the number of characters ins a character values is `nchar`. Downvote for using a picture for data.

Comment: Apologies - question edited to add data

Comment: @Richie Sacramento sorry if this was unclear. Length refers to how many are in each cluster in the final column (col 8). For example, if the following occurs:
55
55
55,
then that flow.type needs to be "1". If there is only one of a number in the cluster (e.g. row 1 in the image) then flow type needs to be "0". The code should count sequentially down the "cluster" column.

Comment: @CatN - OK, based on your sample data, what is your expected output?  This is still not clear.

Comment: In your example of "55 55 55," is the important thing that three of the sequential values in `cluster` matched? If so, you could use `mutate(flow.type = 1 * (lag(cluster, default = 0) == cluster | lead(cluster, default = 0) == cluster))` which would show 1 if the current `cluster` value matches the prior or next value, as would be the case in your example.

Comment: @Jon Spring that worked, thank you!! Sorry i upvoted and accidentally double clicked so it undid.. If you post that comment as an answer i can upvote and tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `flow.type` should be 1 if the `cluster` value is repeated immediately before or after the given row.

One way to capture this would be to use `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::lead` to compare to the preceding or following values. Note, those functions will output NA at the first or last (respectively) rows, so we can specify a default (here `Inf`inity) to match against in those cases, resulting in a clean "0" at the bookends, absent adjacent matches.

```
y %>%
  mutate(flow.type = 1 * (lag(cluster, default = Inf) == cluster | 
                            lead(cluster, default = Inf) == cluster))
```